# Can I average correlation matrices?

Tags: correlation, mean, covariance

the following question comes from a real experimental physics problem.

Imagine I have a certain set of experimental data ($P_{i,1},...P_{i,7}$) for $i \in [|1;N|]$. Here, each $P_{i,j}$ is a real vector of say dimension 100: $P_{i,j}=(p_{i,j,1},...,p_{i,j,100})$ for $i \in [|1;N|]$ and $j \in [|1;7|]$

In an ideal world the all of the $P_{i,j}$ should be iid for all $i \in[|1;N|]$. That is: $$P_1 \sim P_{1,1}\sim P_{2,1} \sim...\sim P_{N,1}$$
$$...$$
$$P_7\sim P_{1,7}\sim P_{2,7} \sim...\sim P_{N,7}$$.

Unfortunately, it is not the case, and we can only reasonably assume that the  $P_{i,j}$ are proportionnal to each other. That is there exist some constants $\alpha_i$ (**which I do not know**) such as :
$$P_1 \sim \alpha_1 P_{1,1}\sim \alpha_2 P_{2,1} \sim...\sim \alpha_N P_{N,1}$$
$$...$$
$$P_7 \sim \alpha_1 P_{1,7}\sim \alpha_2 P_{2,7} \sim...\sim \alpha_N P_{N,7}$$.

I am interested in the statistical links between the representative random variables $P_i$, in particular the covariance matrix $COV$ whose elements are given by $cov(P_j,P_{j'})$ for $(j,j') \in[|1;7|]^2$ or the correlation matrix $COR$ whose elements are given by $corr(P_j,P_{j'})$ for $(j,j') \in[|1;7|]^2$

If the $P_{i,j}$ were iid  (ideal world version), I believe I could average the covariances matrices $COV_i$ whose elements are $cov(P_{i,j},P_{i,j'})$ to get an estimate of $COV$
$$COV\simeq\frac{1}{N}\sum COV_i$$

But because of the unknown  $\alpha_i$ I cannot do that. I was wondering if instead it was reasonable to average correlation matrices to get an estimate of $COR$ instead of covariance matrices, as in these the multiplicative factors do not play a role.

$$COR \simeq \frac{1}{N}\sum COR_i$$

I think I can, but am I missing something ?

**Additional information**

The data comes from a very complicated cold atoms experimental setup. It is hard to get data. In actuality $N=8$, and the vectors dimensions is 50 not 100.

Comment: Sure, you can get *some* estimate in this fashion.  It would even be mathematically plausible, because the mean of correlation matrices is still a correlation matrix.  The question to ask, though, is *how good an estimate would it be?*  It is likely that the arithmetic mean of correlation matrices would be inferior to other estimators.  To determine whether that's the case, we would need to know (a) your sample sizes and (b) enough about your model and/or data to understand how the correlation coefficients are likely to be distributed.

Comment: @whuber , I have made a litlle edit to my question. In actuality $N=8$ and the dimension of the vectors is 50 not  100. I know it's not much.
There are many experimental noises that perturb the real distribution of the $P_i$ and so I cannot even begin to give a theoretical expression for these distributions, as it would take several pages.  What other kinds of estimators do you have in mind ?

Comment: @whuber, The $P_i$ supposedly represent population of a many body spin system (in particular before this system starts interacting), ideally, if no other experimental noises were tainting the measurements, they would have an expected value $E(P_i)$ and a standard deviation $\sqrt{E(Pi)}$ . The other noises are really too complicated for this discussion

Comment: The difficulty is that this tells us little about how the correlation coefficients will be distributed.

Comment: Most likely there is.  Typically one combines the data in some model-appropriate way, computes a combined covariance matrix, and derives the correlation matrix from that.  I'm not prepared to be more specific because I don't feel that I understand the particulars of your situation: the description is just too abstract and looks like it would take a lot of effort to decipher.  Offering a small but characteristic example--preferably with actual or realistic data--can help make questions like this more immediately understandable.